# Manage multiple systems for a job using Jenkins

Tags: resources, continuous-integration, jenkins

I'm pretty new to Jenkins and I'm not sure if it can be used for the following:

- We have multiple branches (let's say 5 branches)
- For each branch we have to run a test suite that requires 2 servers, 1 linux client and 1 
  windows client
- We want to share these resources between the jobs, say that we have a pool of 6 servers, 3 linux clients and 3 windows clients

Is it possible to manage this through Jenkins? The job can be kicked off through a simple shell script, but it has to "reserve" the resources and pass these as parameters to the shell script. It should also queue the test suite jobs if no resources are currently available.

I looked into the Jenkins basis but so far only found the "build slave" model, where you run jobs on managed clients. But I haven't found any solution to manage multiple resources yet. Is that possible through Jenkins?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: related link http://www.cloudbees.com/sites/default/files/whitepapers/7WaysToOptimizeJenkins.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible through Jenkins. You must have assigned labels to your slave nodes, so jobs can be so designed that they use pairs of linux and windows. While configuring the job assign, in the textbox, "Restrict where this project can be run" -> "Label Expression" labels of your slaves.

[image]

you can also find above icon there from here you can find about the various operators that can be utilized for putting conditions also.

Also take reference from [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds) if you are new to Jenkins

Comment: Thanks, this sounds promising, I'm looking into it